# How to get specific data within P tag during web scraping?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape data from a website which has information inside P tag. The only data i'm interested in is **contact** which is in the same P tag. How can i get only the required data?

***Here is the ss of the website. How can i get the text from Company to tel no.?***

[image: Here is the ss of the website. How can i get the text from Company to tel no.?]

Comment: i was just able to get the whole text using normal for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re` module to parse the text.

For example:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.forpressrelease.com/forpressrelease/553538/4/china-leading-cabinet-handles-supplier-rochehandle-celebrates-success-of-entering-european-market'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

txt = soup.select_one('.single_page_content').get_text(strip=True, separator='\n')

company = re.findall(r'Company:\s*(.*)', txt)[0]
address = re.findall(r'Address:\s*(.*)', txt)[0]
contact = re.findall(r'Contact:\s*(.*)', txt)[0]
email = re.findall(r'Email:\s*(.*?)\s*(?=\w+:)', txt, flags=re.S)[0]
tel = re.findall(r'Tel:\s*(.*)', txt)[0]
mob = re.findall(r'Mob:\s*(.*)', txt)[0]
url = re.findall(r'Url\s*:\s*-\s*(.*)', txt, flags=re.S)[0]

print('{:<15}: {}'.format('Company', company))
print('{:<15}: {}'.format('Address', address))
print('{:<15}: {}'.format('Contact', contact))
print('{:<15}: {}'.format('Email', email))
print('{:<15}: {}'.format('Tel', tel))
print('{:<15}: {}'.format('Mob', mob))
print('{:<15}: {}'.format('Url', url))
```

Prints:

```
Company        : Dongguan Roche Industrial Co., Ltd
Address        : No.83, XiZheng 1st Road, Shajiao Community, Humen Town, Dongguan City, Guangdong Province, China 523936
Contact        : Robin Luo
Email          : info@rochehandle.com
Tel            : 0769-89366747
Mob            : +86-13392706499
Url            : https://www.rochehandle.com
```

Comment: it works fine for the given site but when i try this on **https://www.forpressrelease.com/forpressrelease/553537/4/bild-co-announces-seven-game-changing-strategies-for-seniors-housing-industry-investors-and-operators** it gives the error  ** company = re.findall(r'Company:\s*(.*)', txt)[0]
IndexError: list index out of range**

Comment: Because there's an entry that's missing the "Company" field. If you see my answer, there's a check to make sure there is a match before trying to extract it.

Comment: If some answers help you to solve your problem, don't forget to accept and mark them as useful. That will motivate others to help you again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use regular expressions to parse the `<P>` block you get from BeautifulSoup:

```py
import re

text_from_p = """
some text
some more
Tel: 0234-234345-45

some more text
"""

match = re.search(r"Tel: (?P<tel>[0-9\- ]*)", text_from_p)
if match:
    print(match.group("tel"))
else:
    print("Tel not found")
```

You get:

```
0234-234345-45
```